# Line segment sphere intersection test c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, line, intersection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing for ray-sphere intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062286/testing-for-ray-sphere-intersection)

Hi There,

My maths has gotten a little rudimentary, how would I code a line segment / sphere intersection test? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I take it you've tried Googling "line segment / sphere intersection"?

Comment: Yeah, I find the maths a little hard to follow and I can't find any clear code solutions

Comment: In principle there is a distinction between the *title* of the proposed duplicate and this questions, but the *text* of the proposed duplicate matches exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[Point-Line Distance--3-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html). Sphere intersection test results obviously from it.